# Are there potential problems with this sukkah?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, sukkot

I plan on making two walls of my sukkah from wooden panels constructed out of vertical slats nailed to a horizontal wooden slat at the top and bottom. The walls will be just over 10 tefachim high and the slats are 4.2 cm (slightly less than 1 2/3 inches) wide. I wasn't planning on having any horizontal slats other than the top and bottom ones.

I am confident that there are no halachic issues in my planned configuration (with slats adjacent to each other and their ends resting on the ground). In the interests of Torah study, though, I'd like to know of the potential issues that can arise if I change this, even minority positions that do not represent consensus halacha:

Particularly:

What if the vertical gap between the slats were less than a tefach but more than the width of a slat, so the majority of the wall was empty space?
What if the vertical gap between slats were more than a tefach but less than three tefachim?
What if the bottom slat was above the ground, but by less than a tefach?
What if the bottom slat were above the ground by more than a tefach, but less than three tefachim?

Comment: Welcome to MY! Please take a look at our [tour] for some useful information about the site. Unfortunately, MY can’t provide practical halachic guidance; that’s what your Rabbi is for. Gut voch and chag sameiach!

Comment: Ask dinonline ,they have reputable poskim who can answer such questions.

Comment: It was a theoretical question; I rewrote that to make it clear.

Comment: Isn't that how lavud straps work?